# PHP - How to handle unicode received from HTTP POST in order to show them in HTML

Tags: php, unicode

How to convert something like this

> \xe6\xa6\x82\xe8\xa6\x81\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xaa\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x82\xa8\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x83\x8b\xe3\x82\xa2\xe3\x81\xab\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe5\x8b\x9f\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\xbf\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x80\x81\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe5\x8b\x9f\xe5\x89\x8d\xe3\x81\xab\xe8\x87\xaa\xe5\x88\x86\xe3\x81\xae\xe5\xae\x9f\xe5\x8a\x9b\xe3\x82\x92\xe8\xa9\xa6\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\xbf\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe5\x9c\xb0\xe6\x96\xb9\xe3\x81\xab\xe4\xbd\x8f\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\xa7\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe5\x9b\x9e\xe6\x95\xb0\xe3\x81\x8c\xe5\xb0\x91\xe3\x81\xaa\xe3\x81\x84\xe6\x96\xb9\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x82\x8a\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe3\x81\xaf\xe8\x8b\xa6\xe6\x89\x8b\xe3\x81\xa0\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xad\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\x9f\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xaf\xe8\x87\xaa\xe4\xbf\xa1\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x80\x82\xe3\x81\xaf\xe3\x80\x81\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x82\x88\xe3\x81\x86\xe3\x81\xaa\xe6\x96\xb9\xe3\x80\x85\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\x94\xe8\xa6\x81\xe6\x9c\x9b\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\x8a\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe3\x81\x88\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x82\x81\xe3\x81\xab\xe4\xbd\x9c\xe3\x82\x89\xe3\x82\x8c\xe3\x81\x9f\xe6\x96\xb0\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\x84\xe6\x8e\xa1\xe7\x94\xa8\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xad\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\xa0\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xad\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\x9f\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x82\xad\xe3\x83\xab\xe3\x82\x92\xe8\xa9\x95\xe4\xbe\xa1\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x82\x8b\xef\xbc\x91\xe6\xac\xa1\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe3\x82\x92\xe3\x83\x91\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x8d\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\xa7\xe5\x8a\xb9\xe7\x8e\x87\xe7\x9a\x84\xe3\x81\xaa\xe8\xbb\xa2\xe8\x81\xb7\xe6\xb4\xbb\xe5\x8b\x95\xe3\x82\x92\xe8\xa1\x8c\xe3\x81\xa3\xe3\x81\xa6\xe9\xa0\x82\xe3\x81\x91\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x82\x82\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x82\x8d\xe3\x82\x93\xe5\xad\xa6\xe7\x94\x9f\xe3\x81\xae\xe7\x9a\x86\xe3\x81\x95\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x83\x81\xe3\x83\xa3\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x82\x82\xe3\x81\x8a\xe5\xbe\x85\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\x8a\xe3\x82\x8a\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x80\x82

which i received in HTTP POST to show them properly on HTML web page.

I have no idea what I am looking at but i think i can be converted to something which look in this `&#x263A;` format.

How can i do this in PHP

Comment: How do you generate that output (from beginning to end please)?

Comment: i got that in a HTTP POST variable. Initially it was a japanese text.

Comment: And are you really sure that **at the beginning an \ is not missing?**

Comment: oh yes. '\' was missing. sorry for the typo. just updated the question.

Comment: can we see the server side code.. it is a server side issue.. are you encoding when you send the response either using mb_convert_encoding or  utf8_encode for utf-16 and utf-8 encoding respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send the appropriate character set encoding with your HTTP response, you don't have to do anything to the data, the browser should properly decode it as Japanese text.

Example:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$var = "\xe6\xa6\x82\xe8\xa6\x81\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xaa\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x82\xa8\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x83\x8b\xe3\x82\xa2\xe3\x81\xab\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe5\x8b\x9f\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\xbf\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x80\x81\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe5\x8b\x9f\xe5\x89\x8d\xe3\x81\xab\xe8\x87\xaa\xe5\x88\x86\xe3\x81\xae\xe5\xae\x9f\xe5\x8a\x9b\xe3\x82\x92\xe8\xa9\xa6\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\xbf\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe5\x9c\xb0\xe6\x96\xb9\xe3\x81\xab\xe4\xbd\x8f\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\xa7\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe5\x9b\x9e\xe6\x95\xb0\xe3\x81\x8c\xe5\xb0\x91\xe3\x81\xaa\xe3\x81\x84\xe6\x96\xb9\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x82\x8a\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe3\x81\xaf\xe8\x8b\xa6\xe6\x89\x8b\xe3\x81\xa0\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xad\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\x9f\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xaf\xe8\x87\xaa\xe4\xbf\xa1\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x80\x82\xe3\x81\xaf\xe3\x80\x81\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x82\x88\xe3\x81\x86\xe3\x81\xaa\xe6\x96\xb9\xe3\x80\x85\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\x94\xe8\xa6\x81\xe6\x9c\x9b\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\x8a\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe3\x81\x88\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x82\x81\xe3\x81\xab\xe4\xbd\x9c\xe3\x82\x89\xe3\x82\x8c\xe3\x81\x9f\xe6\x96\xb0\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\x84\xe6\x8e\xa1\xe7\x94\xa8\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xad\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\xa0\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xad\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\x9f\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x82\xad\xe3\x83\xab\xe3\x82\x92\xe8\xa9\x95\xe4\xbe\xa1\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x82\x8b\xef\xbc\x91\xe6\xac\xa1\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe3\x82\x92\xe3\x83\x91\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x8d\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\xa7\xe5\x8a\xb9\xe7\x8e\x87\xe7\x9a\x84\xe3\x81\xaa\xe8\xbb\xa2\xe8\x81\xb7\xe6\xb4\xbb\xe5\x8b\x95\xe3\x82\x92\xe8\xa1\x8c\xe3\x81\xa3\xe3\x81\xa6\xe9\xa0\x82\xe3\x81\x91\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x82\x82\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x82\x8d\xe3\x82\x93\xe5\xad\xa6\xe7\x94\x9f\xe3\x81\xae\xe7\x9a\x86\xe3\x81\x95\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x83\x81\xe3\x83\xa3\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x82\x82\xe3\x81\x8a\xe5\xbe\x85\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\x8a\xe3\x82\x8a\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x80\x82";

echo $var;
```

Since we send a header saying that the character encoding is UTF-8, the browser knows to decode it as such.  You could also use a meta-tag to specify the charset.  If the browser was set to auto-detect the code, neither option is necessary, but you can't rely on that.

Comment: got it. it works. how can i store it into database and later publish it as html?

Comment: In the above example, you can just insert `$var` as it stands into the database.  Make sure to escape it (e.g. mysql_real_escape_string).  Then when you read it back, just `echo` it as usual and make sure you have the character encoding specified and it should serve as HTML.

Comment: @drew010: Literal string is not the same as using `eval` (or evaluating an expression like you posted it as an answer).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Japan

```
php > echo "\xe6\xa6\x82\xe8\xa6\x81\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xaa\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x82\xa8\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x83\x8b\xe3\x82\xa2\xe3\x81\xab\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe5\x8b\x9f\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\xbf\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x80\x81\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe5\x8b\x9f\xe5\x89\x8d\xe3\x81\xab\xe8\x87\xaa\xe5\x88\x86\xe3\x81\xae\xe5\xae\x9f\xe5\x8a\x9b\xe3\x82\x92\xe8\xa9\xa6\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\xbf\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe5\x9c\xb0\xe6\x96\xb9\xe3\x81\xab\xe4\xbd\x8f\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\xa7\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe5\x9b\x9e\xe6\x95\xb0\xe3\x81\x8c\xe5\xb0\x91\xe3\x81\xaa\xe3\x81\x84\xe6\x96\xb9\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x82\x8a\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe3\x81\xaf\xe8\x8b\xa6\xe6\x89\x8b\xe3\x81\xa0\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xad\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\x9f\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xaf\xe8\x87\xaa\xe4\xbf\xa1\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x80\x82\xe3\x81\xaf\xe3\x80\x81\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x82\x88\xe3\x81\x86\xe3\x81\xaa\xe6\x96\xb9\xe3\x80\x85\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\x94\xe8\xa6\x81\xe6\x9c\x9b\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\x8a\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe3\x81\x88\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x82\x81\xe3\x81\xab\xe4\xbd\x9c\xe3\x82\x89\xe3\x82\x8c\xe3\x81\x9f\xe6\x96\xb0\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\x84\xe6\x8e\xa1\xe7\x94\xa8\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xad\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\xa0\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xad\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\x9f\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb0\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x82\xad\xe3\x83\xab\xe3\x82\x92\xe8\xa9\x95\xe4\xbe\xa1\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x82\x8b\xef\xbc\x91\xe6\xac\xa1\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe3\x82\x92\xe3\x83\x91\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x8d\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\xa7\xe5\x8a\xb9\xe7\x8e\x87\xe7\x9a\x84\xe3\x81\xaa\xe8\xbb\xa2\xe8\x81\xb7\xe6\xb4\xbb\xe5\x8b\x95\xe3\x82\x92\xe8\xa1\x8c\xe3\x81\xa3\xe3\x81\xa6\xe9\xa0\x82\xe3\x81\x91\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x80\x82\n\xe3\x82\x82\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x82\x8d\xe3\x82\x93\xe5\xad\xa6\xe7\x94\x9f\xe3\x81\xae\xe7\x9a\x86\xe3\x81\x95\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x83\x81\xe3\x83\xa3\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x82\x82\xe3\x81\x8a\xe5\xbe\x85\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\x8a\xe3\x82\x8a\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x80\x82";
概要
・グリーのエンジニアに応募してみたいが、応募前に自分の実力を試してみたい。
・地方に住んでいるので面接回数が少ない方がありがたい。
・面接は苦手だがプログラミングには自信がある。は、このような方々のご要望にお応えするために作られた新しい採用プログラムです。
プログラミングスキルを評価する１次面接をパスできますので効率的な転職活動を行って頂けます。
もちろん学生の皆さんのチャレンジもお待ちしております。
```

The google translate

> Summary
>   -But I would like to apply for the engineers of the glee, want to try their strength before application.
>   The smaller the number of times, because they appreciate the interview live in rural areas.
>   • The programming is confident but not good interview. Is a new adoption program was created to meet the needs of people like this.
>   You can Tenshoku efficient activities so you can pass the next one interview to evaluate the programming.
>   We look forward to challenge of course students

Maybe I'm wrong ;)

Comment: yes it is. I have no idea how can i convert it into hex encoded html.

Comment: just check the other posts below they just correct :) In a few words http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: @Shiv Deepak: The `eval` I posted does this. If you don't want to use eval, there are other ways, e.g. `array_map`, `sscanf` and `pack`.

Answer (score -1):

I have actually no real clue why you get this as POST, but I assume that

```
\x82
```

(and the like) stands for a hexa-decimal number. To convert a whole string (ensure it's that format):

```
$string = eval('return "' . $thatExactInputAsGiven . '";');
```

`$string` does now contain the byte-sequence that this submission represents. However I can not tell you which encoding it is in, but probably this one-line above helps you for testing.

If you fear the eval, mind the error handling:

```
$string = implode('', array_map(function($v){
    $r = sscanf($v, '\x%x', $ord);
    if (!$r) throw new Exception('Invalid input.');
    return chr($ord);
}, str_split($thatExactInputAsGiven, 4)));
```

Comment: @kijin: What looks dangerous? `\x??` ?

Comment: I meant that the eval. But I can see that you added some checks to fix that.